# Labeling a plot frame

Tags: plotting, overlay

I am trying to label the frame of an overlay plot I have made. However, it is not working at all. Here is my code:

```
A2 = A[[15 ;; 31, 2]];
PlotA = ListLinePlot[A2, PlotStyle -> Red, ImagePadding -> 25, 
   Frame -> {True, False, True, True}, 
   FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[15], 
   FrameTicks -> {{{2, 1995}, {7, 2000}, {12, 2005}, {17, 2010}}, 
     None, {{2, 1995}, {7, 2000}, {12, 2005}, {17, 2010}}, All}, 
   FrameStyle -> {Automatic, Automatic, Automatic, Red}, 
   FrameLabel -> {{False, "Consumption"}, {"Year", "Year"}}];
C2 = Consumption[[1 ;; 17, 2]];
PlotC = ListLinePlot[C2, PlotStyle -> Blue, ImagePadding -> 25, 
   Frame -> {False, True, False, False}, 
   FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[15], 
   FrameStyle -> {Automatic, Blue, Automatic, Automatic}, 
   FrameLabel -> {{False, "Affordability"}, {False, False}} ];
Overlay[{PlotA, PlotC}]
```

[image]

Am I going about it the right way? When the plot is displayed, no labels are visible.

Comment: Please include a data sample. Your problem probably boils down to increasing `ImagePadding -> `.

Comment: Josh, you have asked two questions and you haven't accepted any so far. Please check [this link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) regarding why accepting answers.

Answer (score 3):

You can also do the following with any plot:

```
A2 = RandomReal[1, 16];
C2 = RandomReal[1, 17];
PlotA = ListLinePlot[A2, PlotStyle -> Red, ImagePadding -> 25, 
   Frame -> {True, False, True, True}, 
   FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[15], 
   FrameTicks -> {{{2, 1995}, {7, 2000}, {12, 2005}, {17, 2010}}, 
     None, {{2, 1995}, {7, 2000}, {12, 2005}, {17, 2010}}, All}, 
   FrameStyle -> {Automatic, Automatic, Automatic, Red}];
PlotC = ListLinePlot[C2, PlotStyle -> Blue, ImagePadding -> 25, 
   Frame -> {False, True, False, False}, 
   FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[15], 
   FrameStyle -> {Automatic, Blue, Automatic, Automatic}];
plot = Overlay[{PlotA, PlotC}]

Labeled[plot, 
  {Rotate[Style["Affordability", Blue], 90 °], 
   Rotate[Style["Consumption", Red], 90 °], 
   "Year", "Year"}, 
  {Left, Right, Top, Bottom}]
```

Or as kguler points out in [his comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/48260/labeling-a-plot-frame/48262?noredirect=1#comment144209_48262):

```
Labeled[plot, 
  {Style["Affordability", Blue], 
   Style["Consumption", Red], 
   "Year", "Year"}, 
  {Left, Right, Top, Bottom}, RotateLabel -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: You can also use the option `RotateLabel->True` to get rotated labels for `Left` and `Right` sides (+1).

Comment: @kguler Thank you, I edited accordingly :)

Answer (score 2):

Using

```
A2 = RandomReal[1, 16];
C2 = RandomReal[1, 17];
```

and increasing `ImagePadding -> 55`:

[image]

Notice that you have to use `None` not `False` if you don't want particular label.

Comment: Thank you very much, yes it was just the ImagePadding that caused the error.

Comment: @Josh Great :) please, take a [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)